# Find out why a machine was created

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is there any way for a GCP Compute Engine instance to know if it was created by the Instance Group auto-scaling policy or if it was manually created?

On logs we generate on our instances we include the instance id. This is fine for manual instances that are started to test something, but it's not that useful for other instances as it clutters graphs of machine metrics.

In other words, for test machines we need the instance's id, but for other machines we need to log something else that's common to them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can see who perform the creation task in [stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk#query_log_entries_in_the_logs_viewer) by using the following filter:

resource.type="gce_instance"
"create"

You can select a log and expand it to see if the VM was created by a user (email) or by the Instance group manager.

Note: Please have in mind that stackdriver has [retention periods](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods) for the logs.